# Reading LUKS encrypted devices under FreeBSD

Tags: encryption, freebsd, luks

I have currently Debian installed. All my external devices a encrypted LUKS devices.

Now I want to switch to FreeBSD, but my question is, is it possible to read my devices under FreeBSD?

Answer (score 0):

So long as you have cryptsetup installed on FreeBSD and the needed passwords/passphrases other credentials as needed to unlock them YES!!!

Comment: Do you have a package link or reference? All I found was ["FreeBSD doesn't support Linux' LUKS"](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/compatibility-for-cryptsetup-linux.41991/) from 2013